# Editing email templates

Tags: magento

this is probably really easy, but here goes:

My changes to the magento email templates don't show in the emails.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to reinstall magento to get the updates? Am I simply editing the wrong files?

Thanks...

UPDATE: So now:

- I have a fresh magento install
- I haven't touched the Transactional Emails admin
- I don't have locale set to 'en_US' (but since 1.4 that shouldn't be a problem right? Anyway, I tried setting the locale but it didn't help)
- I ERASED the entire app/locale/en_US/template/email/ catalog

With this setup I completed an order and I still get the default email.

The only thing I can think of is I'm coming at this from the wrong direction, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: What files are you editing, what specific emails do you expect them to change?

Comment: I want to make changes to a few emails, but most notably the email the customer gets after completing an order. I've made changes to all the "new"-mails in the sales catalog just to make sure, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your email templates are already saved into the database, and that your changes of the files are therefore not editing the correct version of the templates? Take a look at System -> Transactional Emails to see any templates that have been "promoted" to the database.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: It was certainly a good guess, and you where half-way right. The original templates had been cached. Or something... Deleting the cache folder did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the proper locale selected within the admin if you are using the Transactional Emails to create new templates. Also you can also edit the files directly via

> /app/locale/[language]-[country]/template/email/